# How to get property names of a pojo class without public no-arg constructor?

Tags: java, reflection, pojo, apache-commons-beanutils

I want to get an array(or list) of a POJO's property names .
I tried commons-beanutil's `BeanUtils.describe(obj)` , but it needs an object instance.
But what if I only have that class , without a public no-arg constructor . I cannot use `clazz.newInstance()` to generate an object.

How should I solve it ? Is there any libraries that can dig into a class and pass property names ?

(I know I can use reflection to manually parse the class structure , but I am looking for a handy library)

Thanks.

Comment: It is sad there is no `BeanUtils.describe(Class)` overload to do this.  Why not try implementing it and contributing it as a patch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used it (or anything in `java.beans`, for that matter), but `java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Class)` may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks , it seems there's no existent handy libraries . And java.beans.Introspector is a good utility to finish this job. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Java has its build in reflection utils - which you can use. Hava a look at the [java doc of Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

For example using reflection`Demo.class.getMethods();` to get all getter methods of a Class called `Demo` (without instanciating it.)

```
List<Method> allGetterMethodsOfClassDemo() = new ArrayList<Method>();
for(Method method : Demo.class.getMethods()){
  if(method.getName().startsWith("get") || method.getName().startsWith("is")) {
    allGetterMethodsOfClassDemo.add(method);
  }
}
```

Comment: You may need to add *is* methods for boolean types. ;) getters also have no parameters and cannot have a return type of void.class. (tedious, nes pa ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: thanks for the hint, i have added the "is" prefix. - The other remarks are right, too.

Comment: Oh and the next letter needs to be upper case. :(.  Had  methods like "Field getable(String)" and "void isolate(String)"

Comment: And there must be a setter and a field with the same name. But the fields first letter is lower case. If there are more then 2 upper case letter at the beginning, then the fields letter are lowercased too (for example getWWWFlag() <--> wwwflag) ....